# edge://settings shortcut url not working in custom html code

Tags: windows-10, browser, html

dear community I would like to open edge settings from html code but its not working can you help me out please? when I make simple a href, nothing will happen in edge, why?

```
<a href="edge://settings/appearance">settings</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you open the Development tools of Edge and try this HTML segment,
you will see this error message:

> Not allowed to load local resource: edge://settings/appearance

Security measures dictate that local browser settings should not be
modifiable by browsed pages, which is why this URL is blocked.

To note that any other browser than Edge will say that it
doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (edge)
isn't associated with any program.

Comment: thanks Im trying to make custom start page for ms edge so other browser doesnt matter

is there any policy to tweak to make this HTML segment work for edge?

Comment: Not that I know of. Most browsers today are quite fanatical regarding security.